# SQL Server DB stop from being copied

Tags: sql-server

I have some SQL server DBs attached to my instance.  The problem is they can easily be copied from the physical folder and any one can attach them to his own instance and view data.

How can I make sure that when files are attached, they can not be copied from the physical location and can be copied only when detached from the instance?

Thanks

Comment: At the point at which someone has administrator access to the machine on which SQL Server is running, you've already lost the game.

Comment: You need to provide more information eg. server types, who needs to log on to the server and what they need to do vs what you don't want them to be able to do etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems to me someone have access to the file system. Your database .mdf files can only be as secure as the file system. But here are the few things that will help.

- You can encrypt the data before it goes into the database. Use a long encryption key, to difficult to bruteforce to be worthwhile.
- Also you can consider to change the file extension. There's no law that says you have to use MDF and LDF.
- IMO, you may put the database files in a obscure directory. Don't use MSSQL\DATA.

Hope all these tips will help :)

Comment: great, As you advised I used to place my database on to windows directory by renaming it to .dll

Answer (score 2):

Considering it's SQL server I am assuming you are using Windows environment. The ideal situation would be to have it on a separate server where only few people have access.

If it's a smaller setup then restrict unwanted access to folders by applying security and only allowing yourself and trusted users access to the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)? It's specifically intended to prevent people from accessing the actual files.

> Transparent data encryption (TDE) performs real-time I/O encryption
>   and decryption of the data and log files.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that as you said you will be able to copy the .mdf file while SQL Server service is running

You may disable the Builtin\Administrators user to restrict the Windows Authentication